# When I start my laptop it is showing: You are in emergency mode

Tags: boot

I have host OS as Ubuntu and CentOS in VMware Workstation. I had tried to enable sharing between host machine and virtual machine and this problem occurred.

[image: I]

```
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view   
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit"   
to boot into default mode".
```

Comment: You will have to continue in maintenance mode and modify your `/etc/fstab` and comment out that mount for now until you can figure out how to get it to mount properly.